# Cut from string and put on other position on same string

Tags: php

I have a string with more than 1000+ symbols, and I need to find substring, cut it from curret position and put into another pisition on same string.

P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

```
//I have
$string = "< p>< img class='classes' src='https://example.com/img/img.jpg' atl='img'>< /p>";

// I need
$string = "< p>< img class='classes' data-src='https://example.com/img/img.jpg' src=' ' atl='img'>< /p>";
```

I need find in $string src, cut the link and place it to same  but in data-src

Comment: Why don't you just change 'src' to 'data-src' instead?

Comment: Taking @sorayadragon suggestion you could do `$string = str_replace("src='", "data-src='", $string);`

Comment: @Claudio It might be better idea to replace `" src='"` with `" data-src='"`. Otherwise it might turn `data-src='` into `data-data-src='` if there already is data-src attribute.

Comment: @Michal Hynčica and Claudio thank you very much, i thik i will be use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex by using the `preg_replace_callback` function like:

```
$string = "<p><img class='classes' src='https://example.com/img/img.jpg' atl='img' /></p>";

preg_replace_callback('#\s+src(\s+)?=(\s+)?(\'|")([^\'"]+)(\'|")#', function($m){
    return ' data-src="'.$m[4].'" src=""';
}, $string);

echo $string;
```

Comment: Don't use regex to parse html - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2755347

Comment: @Bradley4 It doesn't hurt for something basic like this. Regex have been used to parse shortcodes and bbcode for years.